# get the title from a context

Tags: javascript, jquery

How Do I select the title of the context? I am suppose to select it to change the title of the page.

```
var handler = function(context){
    document.title = //context's title
    ....
}

//sample context from ajax request
var context = '<!DOCTYPE html><html>\
            <head><title>Hello</title></head>\
            <body>\
            <a href="#">Click Here</a><p>This is my sentence.</p>\
            </body></html>';

.ajax{(
    ...
    success: function(data){
                 handler(data);
             }
});
```

---

**EDIT**: I forgot the doctype just incase it's necessary. The context was from an AJAX Request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the title as well

```
var matches = context.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
var title = matches[1];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zRJg2/1/)

---

Just discovered a way to do this, the non-regex way

```
title = $(context).filter("title");
console.log(title.html());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tW7b9/)

Comment: (whole context value) has no method 'find'

Comment: @JackSpairow, When its wrapped with jQuery's `$`, it is.

Comment: The **Regex** worked. Though I don't know why the other methods don't.

Comment: @JackSpairow, I am not sure, I am trying to find that out.

Comment: @JackSpairow, I think my answer is complete now. Please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to the jquery $ function is the context
So you can try `$("title",$(context)).text()`

Comment: it seems to be returning an empty string as well.

Answer (score 1):

[this should do](http://jsfiddle.net/THdaC/):

```
var title = $(context).eq(0).text()
```

Comment: (whole context value) has no method 'find'

Comment: it seems to be returning an empty string.

Comment: @JackSpairow updated. seems like jQuery's getting iffy with the `<html>`

Comment: @JackSpairow see the demo. it' returns `Hello`

Comment: See my updated question, the [*regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10394076/1099531) worked though I don't know why your methods didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
var handler = function(context){

    $xml=$.parseXML(context);
   console.log($($xml).find('title').text());
}


var context = '<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><a href="#">Click Here</a><p>This is my sentence.</p></body></html>';

    handler(context);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MdvWq/

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: (context)

Comment: Yes it is, And i'm checking why it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/sethunath/UAt5p/

```
$(context)[1].innerHTML
```

returns the title

Comment: This also worked, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10394076/1099531) was earlier than you. +1 though, perhaps a little explanation of the code above?

Comment: @Sethunath - Note that not always `<title>` is the first element in `<head>`. When add another element before `<title>`, you code will just fail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but nobody mention this. This is a [popular method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to search for elements in responses:

```
$(function() {
    var context = '<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><a href="#">Click Here</a><p>This is my sentence.</p>< /body></html > ';
    alert($(context).filter("title").html());   //Use filter to get elements you want
    alert($(context).filter("a").html());       //Will get HTML of that link (<a>)
    alert($(context).filter("body > p").html());  //HTML of <p>
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/THdaC/2/